# gdb C++ debugger not working properly on Windows; Visual Studio Code Debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

### Overview

I have been trying to get C++ debugging to work in VS Code for quite some time now with no success.

I followed the [official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference) from Microsoft on setting up debugging in VS Code, but still ran into problems.
For context:

### VS Code config files

`launch.json`

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
    }
  ]
}
```

`tasks.json`

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
      "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### The issue

The problem branches out into two parts.

**1.** Firstly, I normally use `git bash` as my  default shell in Windows, and would like to keep it that way when debugging C++. However, something that seems to be specific to it is an issue with paths. It seems that running the task here leads to the shell ignoring slashes between directories (likely because of the disparate file system interpretations). This can be seen in the following example:

```sh
> Executing task: 'C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe' -g C:\Users\Redact\Desktop\code\Competitive_Programming\Evaluation.cpp -o C:\Users\Redact\Desktop\code\Competitive_Programming\Evaluation.exe <

g++.exe: error: C:UsersRedactDesktopcodeCompetitive_ProgrammingEvaluation.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
The terminal process "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe '-c', ''C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe' -g C:\Users\Redact\Desktop\code\Competitive_Programming\Evaluation.cpp -o C:\Users\Redact\Desktop\code\Competitive_Programming\Evaluation.exe'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

**2.** When running the debugger with either `PowerShell` or `cmd` as the shell, pre-build works as intended and a debugging session is opened, but nothing else happens. The code doesn't stop in the `main` function (as the guide stated it should) nor are any breakpoints hit—indicating it's not running at all:

[image]
([Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY67o.jpg) to see moving gif if it appears still here)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Hello! It seems I have the same issue as your second issue. Nothing happens after pre-biuld step. Could you please tell me what was the problem?

Comment: Hey @DAle, I’d love to, but I haven’t figured it out myself. In fact, I haven’t looked into this in a while, so I’m not quite sure if I’ll have an answer anytime soon. Here’s hoping you can figure it out.

Comment: Same here. Followed exactly https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw to use GCC with MinGW in VSCode. It builds, runs, but ignores all the breakpoints. I see gdb starts, even reports "Thread 1 "test1" hit Breakpoint 1, ... in main () ..." but no stop in IDE

Comment: Oh, actually I got it fixed. I used mistakenly "\msys64\usr\bin" in PATH instead of "\msys64\ucrt64\bin".